# Помогите доработать пересчет цены от количества

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем салют, помоги с решением ибо я деревянный как сапог.

Нарыл тут же вот такое дело:

```js
function qminus(el, min) {
  var e = $(el);
  var compare = parseInt(e.val());
  var i = ((compare - 1) < min) ? min : compare - 1;
  e.val(i);
  show_price($('#sum_here'), $('#price_here'), i);
}

function qplus(el, max) {
  var e = $(el);
  var compare = parseInt(e.val());
  var i = ((compare + 1) > max) ? max : compare + 1;
  e.val(i);
  show_price($('#sum_here'), $('#price_here'), i);
}

function check_qty(el, min, max) {
  var compare = parseInt(el.val());
  if (compare < min) {
    el.val(min);
    alert(min + ' is minimal qty');
  }
  if (compare > max) {
    el.val(max);
    alert(max + ' is maximum qty');
  }
  show_price($('#sum_here'), $('#price_here'), el.val());
}

function show_price(el, pr, ch) {
  var sum = pr.html() * ch;
  el.html(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="price_here">100</span>

<button onclick="qminus('#qty');" class="b-count__button b-count__button_minus" id="minus">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
</button>
<input type="number" onchange="check_qty($(this),1,100);" name="qty" class="b-count__input" id="qty" value="<? echo $qty ?>" />
<button onclick="qplus('#qty');" class="b-count__button b-count__button_plus" id="plus">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

Всё хорошо работает в теме с товаром, мне нравится что сразу показывает пересчет без задержки обработки НО! Не могу присвоить id товара для того что бы на одной странице (на одной странице у меня по 12 товаров в категории) для каждого работал отдельно. В противном случае пересчитывается только 1-й товар не смотря в каком инпуте менять число.

Буду очень рад, если помогут делом, а не "читай справочники или ищи в интернетах". 
Заранее спасибо (:

Comment: `пересчитывается только 1-й товар`, ибо функция вызывается именно с `qminus('#qty')`; Следовательно, обрабатывается только `#qty`.

Comment: Присвоить айди укникальный этим функциям?  вечером попробую  спасибо

Comment: Лучше описать логику а-ля Клик по кнопке -> Поиск инпута -> Обработка этого инпута.

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
function lessPos(event) { // уменьшение количества
  var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var elem2 = $(elem).siblings.('input').val();
  if (elem2 <= 0){
    elem2 = 0;
  } else {
    $(elem).siblings('input').val(elem2-1);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем я сделал добавил уникальный id к сумме, вывод суммы и к check_qty.
Проверил, работает как надо! Цену берет из товара, пересчет в том товаре где нужно! Проверяйте сами)    https://kltattoo.com.ua/shop/RL-round-liner[1](https://kltattoo.com.ua/shop/RL-round-liner)

Всем спасибо :)